# populating checkboxes from xml through jquery

Tags: jquery, xml

im tryin to populate check boxes and set their values from a xml file using jquery by folloowing code... the problem is its not working can anybody plz tell me whats im doin wrong

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "controls.xml",
              dataType: "xml",
              success: function(xml) {
                  var node = $(xml).find('node');
                  var attribute = $(xml).find('node').attr("attribute");
                  //TODO: do something with data
$(xml).find('checkbox').each(function() {
              var value = $(this).text(); // get the value whether the checkbox is checked or not
              var name = $(this).attr("name"); //get the name attribute
              var val = $(this).attr("value"); // get the numeric value of the control e.g. 100

              $("#Controls").append( //append to some parent container
                $("<input/>") // a new input element
                    .attr("type", "checkbox") //of type checkbox
                    .attr("name", name) // with given name
                    .attr("checked", value) // checked="checked" or checked=""
                   .attr("value", val)//value= specified value                
        )
          });



              }
          });
});
```

here is a sample of my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<RootElement>
  <checkbox name="StaticPage" value="100"></checkbox>
  <checkbox name="FlashPage" value="200"></checkbox>
  <checkbox name="PhotoGalary" value="250"></checkbox>
  <checkbox name="CompletePackage" value="1000"></checkbox>
  <checkbox name="DiscountPAckage" value="800"></checkbox>
</RootElement>
```

Comment: what is the error/problem you are facing?

Comment: could you give us a sample of the xml?

Comment: is your URL right?? it says control.xml

Comment: u r url looks like wroing to me

Comment: i have added the xml file in my project root, i have tried ~/controls.xml

Comment: @gov
i think too the prb lies with the url but cant figure out the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its rather embarrassing ...

i changed

```
type: "POST"
```

to

```
type: "GET"
```

problem solved ... tnx everybody

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting any output from your POST request? I would use this to load the XML:

```
$.get("test.php", function(data) {
  alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
});
```

Try making the script `alert()` at every stage to see what it returns and where it dies. That's how I (pathetically, but systematically) debug my JS.

Comment: you can also use firebug's console.log :)

Comment: I like Chrome's Inspector too. Those toolkits really *do* help to debug stuff!